# Failed to initialize Apple Id Client in Bitrise XCode Archive & Export for iOS

Tags: xcode, react-native, bitrise, apple-id

Does anyone encounter this issue in Bitrise > XCode Archive & Export for iOS?
[Bitrise > XCode Archive & Export for iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMWHu.png)

I really don't understand why it is still failing in this part though I already set auths in `Profile > Account settings > Apple Service connection > API keys and Apple ID connection.`

I spent days on this one until now I am stuck.

Anybody can help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Aljohn, did you contact Bitrise support via the on site support option? We'll need more information to be able to figure out what's causing the issue.